# Angular 5 : How to send multiple params in HttpClient Post request?

Tags: angular, web-services, httpclient, angular5

I have been trying to send a POST request with httpClient in Angular5 , but it seems that nothing is working , i don't get any errors at the same time no result .

This is the way i tried :

```
 addProjToClient(idPerson:number,idProject:number){
    if(this.authService.getToken()==null) {
      this.authService.loadToken();
    }

    return this.http.post(this.host+"/saveProjectToClient", {
      idPerson,
      idProject,
    }, {headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})})

  }
```

but the API rest in back end ( spring boot ) is not reachable this way , i tried others solutions in github , even stackoverflow but with no result , any idea ?

**PS : the Api rest is working well when i try to call it with the ARC extention.**

**EDIT : the API rest **

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/saveProjectToClient",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean saveProjectToClient(@RequestBody Dto dto){
        System.out.println("Person id : ");
        System.out.println(dto.getIdPerson());
        System.out.println("Project id : ");
       System.out.println(dto.getIdProject());

         return true;
    }
```

Comment: "not working" is never a good explanation of a problem. Please try to describe the problem thoroughly.

Comment: (I have edited the post with the code of the api rest )  -> When i try to call the api rest using ARC extention it returns 'true' , in console i can see : Persone id : 1 Project id : 2 for exemple , but when i try to call this api in angular , i don't get the result in console ,and there is no error in devlopement tool of chrome

Comment: half of the time when I hear "it works with X client, but not in Angular", it's a CORS problem. Could this be the issue?

Comment: i don't think so , because there is other request with GET , delete , PUT and even POST working well in angular , the problem goes here with the fact that i'm sending multiple params , here 2 parametrs

Comment: Did you try by doing a Class or Interface  where you put all the parameter as class properties. then in the controller you code must looks like this `saveProjectToClient(PostClassCreated params)`

Comment: Those aren't "multiple params". It is one javascript object with multiple properties. And I highly doubt this has anything to do with the fact that there multiple properties.

Comment: @AbelValdez No i didn't , i'll try this right now .

Comment: @PaulSamsotha it's weird that everythings goes well with other clients but not angular

Comment: All `{ a, b }` is is ES6 shorthand syntax for `{ a: a, b: b }`.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha not resolved yet

Comment: @AbelValdez i've Edited the post as you said , can you see the post again i'm fascing some problem  .

Comment: I mean in the back end sorry

Comment: ah okey , i've already did this in back end , with the same method but always the same problem

Comment: is there any errors in chrome console?

Comment: No there is no errors , but the method in back end is not reachable , as i can't see the system.out.println etc , but it works with arc extention